# Control "Notification Centre" settings for iPad app (using Phonegap)

Tags: objective-c, cordova, ios7, push-notification, nsnotificationcenter

Have developed an iPad app using Phonegap that works well along with Push Notifications in iOS 7. But my question is whether there is a possibility to control/modify iOS "Notification Centre" settings from my Phonegap app (programatically).

Ideally, What I prefer to do is to have a toggle button in my main menu in app and toggling it should move my app from "INCLUDE" section in the "Notification Centre" to "DO NOT INCLUDE" section in the "Notification Centre" and vice versa.

Please help me out as I'm a beginner with Objective-C.

Comment: can you explain better what do you want?

Comment: Cesar, Controlling the Push Notification to be sent to a device based on user's choice.

Comment: You can't change Notification Center values from your app

Comment: Thanks Cesar, Sorry for bothering you again... I've a device token and boolean value that stores whether an user has allowed push notifications in the app. Is there anyway that I can store these values to the InAppBrowser's local storage (feel this will provide me a way to control in sending push notification).

Comment: You have to send the push notifications to apple APN and apple will handle the sending and inform you if the user didn't allowed the push notifications (or allowed when was asked but changed it from settings app). You just need the device token, send it to your server when you get it and store it there, or in phonegap localStorage, but not on InAppBrowsers localStorage, because I think it can be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround now to control the user preferences. Its solved now.
Here s the Workaround:
1) Passback the  'Device Token' and a boolean flag which indicates whether user allowed push notification or not to the javascript.
2) Pass the values received to the load URL as URL parameters.
3) Using PHP GET will receive these parameters at the server side and store it to a database table.

Now you can devise your own logic in the app to control push notification to be sent to a particular device(device token is not unique for all apps in a same device) or not.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Apologies Darwind. I think I've explained well now. If not, please have a comment posted and ready to clarify and explain even more!!!